# Install Python3, PIP, Paramiko on Ubuntu Docker Container in GNS3

Tags: python, paramiko

I am having some issues getting the proper items installed. I am trying to get Python3 installed along with `pip3` and `paramiko`.

I first ran these commands:

```bash
apt-get update
apt-get install python3
apt install python3-pip
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

And then I tried installing `paramiko` with both of these commands:

```bash
pip3 install paramiko

pip install paramiko
```

But neither worked and they raised the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
  from pip._internal.cli.main import main
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 58
  sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am still a rookie with Linux stuff and I am sure I'm making a mistake. I'm basically [following this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xd1kI1eq5uw&ab_channel=DavidBombal) from David Bombal.

However, he gave commands to install stuff for Python2, but not Python3. Thank you!

Comment: This might help you, question and answer from askUbuntu.
[Pip is not working: ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025189/pip-is-not-working-importerror-no-module-named-pip-internal)

Comment: Thanks, the link you posted helped me realize that upgrading pip is what's causing that specific error in the OP. However, I'm still unable to get this installed with leaving pip on version 8.1.1.

When running python3 -m pip install --user paramiko, I receive:
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in crytopgraphy

When running python3 -m pip install --user crytopgraphy, I receive:
could not find a version that satisfies requirement crytopgraphy

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```bash
pip3 install paramiko
```

Comment: The OP has already tried that command.